# How to find UTC date/time by city name?

Tags: php, datetime

How to find UTC date/time by city name?

Comment: By what kind of city name - *any* name of any city in the world? The name(s) that are usually part of the time zone like "London"? Please add much more detail and context.

Comment: Assuming you mean UTC time offset: city name alone might not be enough. There are a lot of cities around the world, that share the name, but not the timezone.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please give an example of what you want - the input and your desired output. Please also post what you've tried so far and explain why this doesn't achieve your desired result.

Comment: Actually, if you did mean UTC, then you might be confused. It's the same time in UTC everywhere, regardless of city :)

So maybe you really meant 'how to calculate local time given a city name?'

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want this?:

```
$d = new DateTime("now", new DateTimeZone("Europe/Minsk"));
echo $d->format(DateTime::W3C);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to take a look into [GeoIP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.geoip.php) extension.
It has "geoip_time_zone_by_country_and_region" function. Maybe it could help you.